# Loading a popup draft email in google sheets using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have been working with google apps & script for a while now and have since been unable to figure this out. Is there a decent way to pop-up a draft email with "to", "cc", "subject", "message", "attachments" (attachments can just be drive folder) within google sheets?

I am able to send emails with the above, just would like the added benefit of previewing and editing my canned responses etc. before sent.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display an actual GMail page; Google Apps Script is executed on Google Server and has very limited control over what happens in the browser. It can display messages and accept input, but not open arbitrary webpages as pop-ups.

It's easy to give the user a preview of a message and the option of sending or canceling it: [Browser.msgBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String,String,ButtonSet)) would do.

But there isn't a convenient way of offering to *edit* a text via Browser class: the inputBox method doesn't have an option of pre-filling the box, and in any case its textbox is  a single line, not suitable for editing an email.

I see two options:

1. (Hard) Write a web app using HttpService that will interact with  the user.
2. (Easy but not as nice): show the preview using  `Browser.msgBox`; if the user presses Cancel, put the content of the email in the spreadsheet somewhere, where the user will edit it and then trigger "send" again, e.g., via a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) or a [custom menu option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response -- this is more-or-less what I've come to understand.

Comment: Oops - hit enter too early.

Do you think there is possibility of another option in which I create the draft, and generate a link thereto within the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, for example you can create a Google Document and display a link to it. But this may end up being too much work for "automated" email...

Answer (score 0):

you could open a [custom dialogue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), which can be of any dimension, and can have the functions of a regular webpage. Don't know if this helps, but our team [wrote this code](https://github.com/supertopoz/Google-Script-Snipits/blob/master/SendEmailAttachment) for attaching files to script using GAS.